# how can one configure MongoDB replication set in PHP through sharding architecture?

Tags: php, mongodb, configuration, replication, sharding

I have to develop a php web interface to manage a MongoDB cluster.
This cluster is currently composed by 1 mongos, 1 config, 1 RS (Resplication Set with 5 mongod).
I want to know if it's possible to configure the different RS behind the one or more mongos instances in relation with the client/admin app.

. . . . . . . . . | mongos |
admin app | . . . . . . .  | ==>  RS1 / RS2 / RS3
. . . . . . . . . | mongos |

Is it possible to (re)configure (add/remove/modify members) RS1, RS2 or RS3 with the admin app in this architecture ?

Comment: You cna use `command` function in conjunction with this documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/commands/#replication-commands more specifically the `replSetReconfig` command

Comment: The php method 'command' with 'replSetReconfig()' seems to be executed on the admin DB of the targeted RS ...
But, i don't know how to access the 'admin' DB of the right RS since mongos hide the complexity of the different shards.

Comment: You would have to access the mongod directly I believe, so you would have to make a new connection directly to the shard that has the replica attached and work there